# show modal after submit form

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, form-submit, popup

I want to thank the visitor with a thank you modal after submitting the form.

I have tried several solutions that I've found on the internet. Most of them come from stackoverflow.  I've seen some answers about AJAX, but I am totally unfamiliar with that.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
$naam = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefoon = $_POST['tel'];
$onderwerp = $_POST['onderwerp'];
$bericht = nl2br($_POST['bericht']);
$to = "user@gmail.com";

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>

$naam <br>
$email <br>
$telefoon <br><br>

$bericht <br>

EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

mail($to, $onderwerp, $body, $headers);
header('Location: index.html');
?>
```

I also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/stijns96/pen/KjEJrX)

Is there any jQuery solution for showing a thank you modal right after submitting the form?

Comment: What is processing your form currently when someone submits it? You can use jQuery to run an open modal call on submit of a form, but you would only want the thank you modal to pop open after the data has been validated in some way. Need more context about your form to answer this.

Comment: I have added a codepen to show the form. If the visitor has entered the inputs, I want to thank him / her through a modal box that appears after clicking submit

Answer (score 0):

if your form works with the "POST" method you can wait in php for the POST Request and if the user submits the form.

an example

```html
<?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post">
                      <input name="input" placeholder="edit me">
                      <button name="submit" type="submit" value="edit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

if the user had submitted your form the server will show up the html snippet and the user gets the modal. We need more info for the perfect answer.

//edit

you need to place the snippet on this site "send-mail.php"

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `echo`. In the below I have used `sweet alert`.
If you wanna use `bootstrap modal` you can replace `sweet alert` with `$('#modalId').show(modal)`.

It should be in the below way
**index.php**

```
<form class="border  p-3 bg-light rounded col-sm-10 form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <h3 style="color:#2326b1;width: fit-content;border-radius:10px"> Get In Touch
    </h3><br>
  </div><br><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Name" value="" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email" value="" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobno" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Contact Number" value="" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="sub" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md " style="background-color: #2326b1;padding:5px 10px;font-weight:700">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</form>
<?php include 
$msg = "";
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
include_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sub = $_POST['sub'];
    $mobno = $_POST['mobno'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = ''; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = ''; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->addAddress('xyz@gmail.com', 'XYZ');
    $mail->setFrom('enquiry@gmail.com', 'Enquiry');
    $mail->Subject = "Enquiry";
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = "Name : ";
    $mail->Body.= $name;
    $mail->Body.= "";
    $mail->Body.= "<br/>";
    $mail->Body.= "";
    $mail->Body.= "Mobile No : ";
    $mail->Body.= $mobno;
    $mail->Body.= "";
    $mail->Body.= "<br/>";
    $mail->Body.= "";
    $mail->Body.= "Message : ";
    $mail->Body.= $sub;
    $mail->Body.= "<br/>From : ";
    $mail->Body.= $email;

    if (!$mail->send())
        {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
      else
        {
        echo  '<script> swal("Thank you,'. $name .'.  We will get back to you shortly")</script>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I copied it and pasted it into a new empty index.php file. I then tested this on XAMPP. Unfortunately without result ...

Comment: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>` add this inside your head tag

Comment: you need to include`phpmailer` in your root folder.